# How to supress warning for "Deleted feature: PAUSE statement" in gfortran?

Tags: gfortran, suppress-warnings

I googled it but i could not find the answer. How can I suppress this warning AND ONLY THIS:

Warning: Deleted feature: PAUSE statement at (1)

i know I can supress all the warning but I wanna suppress only this one. Or if not possible. suppress warning for delete features.
thanks
A.

Answer (score 4):

Compile with -std=legacy or -w (lowercase).  Note that -w will suppress all warnings.

Comment: As I said above I already knew that. I want to suppress that specific one or only "deleted features"one. Maybe it is not possible

Comment: Sorry, misread your question.  It is not possible to suppress only 1 deleted feature in gfortran.